# Activate pasted links

Tags: hyperlink, safari, applescript

I have a few routines (sample below) that will create links to documents, web pages etc that I will then paste into Apple Notes or a Devonthink RTF file.

The Links work fine but to activate them in the destination document I have to place the cursor at the end of the link and press enter.

is there a way to simulate this process in Applescript or actually make them active on pasting?

```applescript
tell application "Safari"
    set docText to ""
    set windowCount to count (every window where visible is true)
    repeat with x from 1 to windowCount
        set tabCount to number of tabs in window x
        repeat with y from 1 to tabCount
            set tabName to name of tab y of window x
            set tabURL to URL of tab y of window x as string
            set docText to docText & tabName & " – " & tabURL & return & return as string
        end repeat
        set the clipboard to the docText
        beep
    end repeat
end tell
```

[image: Screenshot of inactive and active links]

Comment: You can paste it into Notes programmatically, and send a return keystroke after pasting.
What I did is set the URL to the clipboard, activate Notes, then send the paste key code, followed by the return keystroke.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the suggestion. I do often though extract multiple links to selected Mail items, Safari Tabs, files etc. Possibly could loop through a process of pasting a link, Return, past link etc.  Food for thought.